# PHP PDO sending parameters

Tags: php, post, pdo, parameters

I've been trying php and I have some problems that i just cant solve with the parameters. If I try to save the parameter on BD by typing it saves otherwise if I try to send it straighten from the code it didn't work.
That's my code.

```
<?php
class Cliente {

    public $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $db = new Database();
        $this->db = $db->instance();
        $this-> sendDado();
    }


    public function sendDado(){
        if ($_POST) {
            try {
                $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO PESSOA(nome, email, func) values(:nome,:email,:func)");
                $query->bindValue(":nome", $_POST['nome'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->bindValue(":email", $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->bindValue(":func", $_POST["1"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $query->execute();
                echo "Enviado com sucesso";
            } catch(PDOException $e) {

                echo "Não foi possivel enviar";
            }
        }   
    }
?>
```

Comment: What does "save the parameter on BD" mean?  Are you getting errors from this code?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Maybe he refers to DB.

Comment: what is $_POST['1']?

Comment: yeah, sorry DB. I'm trying to save those informations on my database, but when I try to run it on browser there is no message error; otherwise, when I check the DB it's empty.

Comment: Show us how you're instantiating and using this class

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the error message (often essential to know when debugging), I can only take a guess.  `$_POST["1"]` looks suspicious.  Do you really have a POST variable with "1" (number one) as its name (is that even allowed)?  Or are you trying to save the integer 1 as the value of "func" in the database?  If yes, change that line to

```
$query->bindValue(":func", 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: There is no error menssage, it acts as it were working, but when I went to the database there is no information. I want to save the value 1, it's not allowed variable named with only numbers.


$query->bindValue(":func", 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);


and this one also didn't work, I tryed before.